# App crashes after FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance

Tags: android, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-authentication

I use FireBase authentication with a simple function that signs up a new user, it works great on the Unity Editor, but when I build it on my Android, it crashes the second it tries to read this line- `FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance`

This is the error I get before it crashes-

> Java class com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuthWebException not found.  Please verify the AAR which contains the com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuthWebException class is included in your app.

1. Why do I even get the Firebase-AuthWeb-Exception ?
2. Why can't it find that exception?  (I tried to resolve jar files, and to re-import auth SDK but it didn't solve the issue

My app is simple- there's a SignUp button that calls this function-

```
 public void SignUp()
 {
    FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance;  //The error is after this line

    auth.CreateUserWithEmailAndPasswordAsync(email.text, password.text).ContinueWith(task =>
    {
        if (task.IsCanceled)
        {
            Debug.LogError("CreateUserWithEmailAndPasswordAsync was canceled.");
            return;
        }
        if (task.IsFaulted)
        {
            Debug.LogError("CreateUserWithEmailAndPasswordAsync encountered an error: " + task.Exception);
            return;
        }

        // Firebase user has been created.
        Firebase.Auth.FirebaseUser newUser = task.Result;


        Debug.LogFormat("Firebase user created successfully: {0} ({1})",
            newUser.DisplayName, newUser.UserId);
       // SignInWithVerification();
    });


}
```

- Unity- 2108.2.12f1
- Build system- Gradle
- Firebase unity sdk 5.4.0 dotnet3

Comment: I am having the same problem with Unity-2018.1.2f1 Linux. I am using the 5.4.0 dotnet4 Firebase plugin, but it already started happening with 5.3.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally fixed it! It was a problem with the dependencies but was impossible to solve, even though I tried Androd-resolve so many times.

-I removed all Firebase files (make sure you remove everything)
-I removed Library folder (under project folder) **not sure if it's necessary 
-I removed AndroidResolverDependencies (under projectsettings folder)
-I removed unity folder in C:\Users***\AppData\Local and C:\Users***\AppData\Roaming
-Installed the Firebase package again
-Android resolve

That's it. Nobody could help me with it so I removed EVERYTHING!
*Save a backup of everything before you try my solution

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I managed to solve this. For me it never crashed, but just because I got this error I assumed it was setting the Auth DefaultInstance as null (while it actually worked).

For clarification, I am using Firebase Auth, Firebase Database, Google Play Services.

The error went away when I downgraded to Firebase 5.2.1. I am not sure why this error makes your app crash, maybe it is something else? You could try removing the line and see if it still crashes.

When I realised that this error doesn't actually harm anything I upgraded back to 5.4.0 and even though I get this error, everything works beyond that.

Comment: I found out that that error doesn't matter. The app crashes with or without it, after I use FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance;  I'm sure it has to do with the libraries

Answer (score 1):

I've got a similar problem with but on Firebase 8.7.0 and Unity 2021.28f1 but removing and re installing everything worked.

But I got it working with

```
FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.GetAuth(app)
```